# RestKit Request Mocking

Tags: objective-c, mocking, restkit

Is there any way to mock the request/response handling of RestKit? I would like to test my application with json fixtures but without using an external server.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution with the following library which mock the complete network traffic on cocoa-level.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs